# Attempting to use list of stacks output as module output

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a module that creates a variable number of CloudFormation Stacks.  This works just fine but I am having problems attempting to use the Stack output as output in the module.  The stack creates a subnet and I specify the created subnet id as an output of the stack.  Then I want to return a list of all subnet ids as part of module output.  This is what I think my output should look like:

```
output "subnets" {
  value = ["${aws_cloudformation_stack.subnets.*.outputs["Subnet"]}"]
}
```

I get an integer parse error when I do that. Terraform seems to be treating outputs as a list instead of a map.  Any way to get this to work?

Edit: Here is where I declare the stacks:

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "subnets" {
  count = "${local.num_zones}"

  name = "Subnet-${element(local.availability_zones, count.index)}"
  on_failure = "DELETE"
  template_body = "${file("${path.module}/templates/subnet.yaml")}"
  parameters {
    CIDR = "${cidrsubnet(var.cidr,ceil(log(local.num_zones * 2, 2)), count.index)}"
    AZ = "${element(local.availability_zones, count.index)}"
    VPC = "${aws_cloudformation_stack.vpc.outputs["VPCId"]}"
  }
}
```

Then there is a Stack output in subnet.yaml that is has key Subnet and is the id of the subnet that was created.

The stacks are all created successfully but I can't seem to get exporting all the created subnet ids from my terraform module. Not sure why terraform is treating *.outputs as list vs keeping *.outputs["Subnet"] as the list.  I'm guessing *.outputs is getting converted to a list of maps but I need a list of a specific key (Subnet) in the map.

I've got a non list example working for stack and using output from stack as terraform module output:

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "vpc" {
  name = "${var.name_prefix}-VPC"
  on_failure = "DELETE"
  template_body = "${file("${path.module}/templates/vpc.yaml")}"
  parameters {
    CIDR = "${var.cidr}"
  }
}

output "vpc" {
  value = "${aws_cloudformation_stack.vpc.outputs["VPCId"]}"
}
```

I was able to work around the issue by declaring data to lookup the subnets after creation.  It's not ideal but gets me passed being stuck.  Let me know if anyone knows how to do what I was originally trying to do.  Here is what I came up with:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "subnets" {
  depends_on = ["aws_cloudformation_stack.subnets"]
  vpc_id = "${aws_cloudformation_stack.vpc.outputs["VPCId"]}"
}

output "subnets" {
  value = "${data.aws_subnet_ids.subnets.ids}"
}
```

Comment: That syntax is going to return a list: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#attributes-of-other-resources. You could maybe leverage the `map` function (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#map-key-value-), but more information would be helpful.

Comment: try: output "subnets" {
  value = "${aws_cloudformation_stack.subnets.*.outputs["Subnet"]}"
}

Comment: @victorm - Both ways return the same error, it's converting outputs as a list then trying to index it numerically so it throws this error: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "Subnet":

Comment: @MattSchuchard - More info would be ultimately I want to be able to get the list of subnet ids created from this module as a comma separate string for use in another module.

Comment: Given the extra information you provided, you would need to filters the values for that specific key out of the list of maps. I am not completely sure if that is possible in < 0.12.

Comment: Ah thanks, I was able to come up with a workaround for my specific case luckily